# Minimum number of elements in a subgroup of a group of $15$ elements

Tags: group-theory

Suppose a group $\mathcal G$ contains $15$ elements. $\mathcal H$ is a subgroup of $\mathcal G$ such that the minimum number of elements in $\mathcal H$ must not be less than $4$. What is the minimum number of elements $\mathcal H$ can have ?

Comment: You mean that $\mathcal{H}$ has at least $4$ elements? Consider what Lagrange tells you about this.

Comment: I know what Lagrange's theorem tells us. But when I'm trying to visualize it with a group $\mathcal{G}=(\mathbb{Z}_{15},+_{15})$ [$+_{15}$ is the addition modulo $15$ operation], I can form a subgroup $\mathcal{H}=(\{0,7,8\},+_{15})$. Now I've to add at least $1$ more element (to be precise $2$, element & its inverse). Here is where I'm unable to find exactly $2$ elements, nothing more, that can be added to make $\mathcal{H}$ of minimum order of $5$. Because whatever element I add, it's making me add even more elements (closure) & eventually the order of $\mathcal{H}$ is finishing at $15$.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. Where did the elements $0$, $7$ and $8$ come from? Those do not form a subgroup, and the smallest subgroup containing them (in fact, containing just one of $7$ or $8$) will be the entire group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a theorem that in the integers mod $n$, the (additive) order of $[k]$ (the equivalence class of the integer $k$ modulo $n$) is:

$\dfrac{n}{\text{gcd}(k,n)}$.

Mod $15$, this means that $1,2,4,7,8,11,13$ all have order $15$, that is: they generate the entire group.

So if you want a SMALLER group, you have to look at the other $7$ elements of $\Bbb Z_{15}$. It's not hard to see that $0$ generates a trivial subgroup, and that $5$ and $10$ both generate a subgroup of order $3$ (because this is $15/5$).

In general, a group of order $15$, can only have subgroups of orders $1,3,5$ or $15$ (as a consequence of Lagrange). If you need $> 4$ elements, this leaves $5,15$ as the only possibilities, and $5$ is smaller.

Comment: Yes ... but I'm having trouble generating an order $5$ subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$.

Comment: Try looking at multiples of 3 mod 15...